# Correct place to create a root actor in the play 2 app

Tags: playframework-2.0, akka, reactivemongo

I'm using Play's Actor system to create my supervisor (root) actor for my app.

The first thing that I need to do with this root actor is send it a message to configure itself and a bunch of child actors. The configuration involves reading from a conf file using TypeSafe config API and then loading these values into a database (MongoDB in this case).
 Since I'm using reactivemongo to load the configuration from the conf file to the database it is completely non-blocking and asynchronous. All other actions in the controller depend on the configuration values being loaded to the database.

It's not clear to me where I should create this actor? I tried creating it in the constructor of my controller but if an action is invoked before the async loading is complete I get an exception.

I also tried putting it inside Global.onStart() but again then I could't get the supervisor inside my controller code.

```
import play.api._

object Global extends GlobalSettings {


  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application has started")
  val supervisor = Akka.system().actorOf(Props(new Supervisor()), "easupervisor")

  }


}
```

I tried creating the supervisor directly in the constructor of the Global object but that gave me a play initialization error as well.

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  val supervisor = Akka.system().actorOf(Props(new Supervisor()), "easupervisor")


  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application has started")

  }    

}
```

Comment: what would be the approach in play 2.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct place is the Global object. The way I usually go about it is to initialise the supervisor in the `onStart` method and to use simple constructor-based dependency-injection:

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {  

  var supervisor: ActorRef = _

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    supervisor = Akka.system().actorOf(Props(new Supervisor()), "easupervisor")
  }

  override def getControllerInstance[A](controllerClass: Class[A]): A = {

    val MY_CONTROLLER = classOf[MyController]

    val instance = controllerClass match {
      case MY_CONTROLLER => new MyController(supervisor)
      case _ => super.getControllerInstance(controllerClass)
    }

    instance.asInstanceOf[A]
  }
}
```

As an alternative you could also fetch the supervisor actor reference using an address in the controller.